# How to get column names from fields

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I have searched the web and looked in the source code of the postgresql-simple package.

The results of a query (or query_) are of type class [QueryResults]. It is easy to get the contents of the fields, but can anyone show some example code for getting the column/field names? The Field class from PostgreSQL.Simple.FromField has a name attribute returning a ByteString with the column name. But I am simply unable to get from this simple example listing the contents:

```
  conn <- connect con
  xs <- query_ conn "select pk,tfrom from feedback"
  forM_ xs $ \(field1,field2) ->
    putStrLn $ T.unpack field2 ++ " has key " ++ show (field1 :: Int)
```

to something that also lists the name of the columns (i.e. pk and tfrom).

Getting the field/column names is very useful when doing select * from a (say, human-readable diagnostics, statistics) stored procedure (or table) so we can easily print the results without changing the code when the table or stored procedure changes.

Edited after answer was provided:
Here is the working code with the first suggestion (B8 is ByteString):

```
  putStrLn $ " is names " ++ (B8.toString (fromJust (name field2))) ++ " " ++ (B8.toString (fromJust (name field1)))
```

Now, there still remains the problem of getting both the data and field names when using the first suggestion as the code will fix the contents to type Field - which does not contain the data itself, just metadata. The second suggestion fixes that, now the working code looks like this:

```
  forM_ xs $ \((data1,field1),(data2,field2)) ->
    putStrLn $ " " ++ (B8.toString (fromJust (F.name field1))) ++ " " ++ (B8.toString (fromJust (F.name field2))) ++ " " ++ (T.unpack data2) ++ " " ++ (show (data1 :: Int))
```

I hope this proves useful for someone else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Postgres instance around to check this at the moment, but you could try introducing `instance FromField Field where fromField f = return . const f` and then use `name` to get the name of your fields out. You might even more generally want

```
instance FromField a => FromField (a, Field) where
  fromField f bs = (,f) <$> fromField f bs
```

Unless I'm pretty mistaken on how this library works, I'm pretty surprised those instances aren't in there.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly, thanks a lot. And no changes required to my code, it just made the code I thought would work -  suddenly work as expected. To anyone going for the second suggestion: it requires TupleSections and FlexibleInstances enabled.

Comment: Your second suggestion gives both the data and the value. See my original question for code example.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer I'm afraid, but too long for a comment.

If you look at the library's source, you'll see the following function in Simple/Internal.hs

```
name Field{..} = unsafePerformIO (PQ.fname result column)
```

The PQ is a reference to libpq (the standard PostgreSQL client library) and [fname](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQFNAME) gets you a fieldname given a resultset and column index. So, clearly it's available.

Now, I don't think this function is exported, and I don't know if there's a way around that since I'm a Haskell newbie. Clearly you could patch the source easily enough.

However, I don't think you'll be able to have a dynamic resultset even with the fieldname available without casting all the query column-types to text (or something similar). Otherwise postgresql-simple will return them as Int or Date or some such.